# Code not returning all list arrays

Tags: python-3.6

I wrote the following code which is a slight variation to yours:

```
shopping_cart = ['pen', 'paper ', 'ink '] #items in shopping cart
out_of_stock = ['pen', 'ink']  #items out of stock

for item in shopping_cart:
    if item in out_of_stock:
        print ("Sorry, " + item + " is out of stock.")
    else:
        print ("Adding " + item + " to your shopping cart")

print ("Your order is complete.")
```

but for some reason it only returns one item out of stock, when there are two:

Sorry, pen is out of stock.
Adding paper to your shopping cart
Adding ink to your shopping cart
Your order is complete.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra space in the `'ink '` string on the first line. `'ink' != 'ink '`

Comment: ha ha! Thank you Jerfov2, that's what it was. Sometimes it's the simplest thing that drives you crazy!